# What is the coequalizer of a pair of projections?

Tags: category-theory

I feel like this should be fairly simple, but I can't quite see how to answer this question: in a category with products and coequalizers, what is the coequalizer of the pair $\pi_1,\pi_2:A\times A\rightrightarrows A$?

My gut feeling says it's the terminal object (it's the case in $\textbf{Set}$), but I'm not sure it even exists in general. Forgive me if this is a basic category theory exercise I never saw.

Comment: Conceptually, the coequalizer of $\pi_1 r$ and $\pi_2 r$, for $r:R\hookrightarrow A\times A$ is in effect the quotient of $A$ by the smallest (partial) equivalence relation containing $R$. So the coequalizer of the projections is the quotient by the *total* relation on $A$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Yes, that's what I was picturing in my head, but I wasn't sure how to demonstrate it formally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE ^_^

If a terminal object $1$ exists, and moreover there is a map $a : 1 \to A$, then yes. The coequalizer is $1$.

Notice we can't drop the existice of a map $1 \to A$ even in $\textbf{Set}$! The empty set modulo the empty relation is not $1$.

But, if $a : 1 \to A$ exists, then it's not hard to show that for any $f : A \to X$ making $f \pi_1 = f \pi_2$ we must also have $f a_1 = f a_2$ for any $a_1, a_2 : 1 \to A$.

Once we take this into account, it is clear that the map $f a : 1 \to X$ makes the coequalizer diagram commute for any choice of arrow $a : 1 \to A$, and we assumed one existed.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up! I didn't think about the empty set. Incidentally, this means that $X$ is also a terminal object, right?

Comment: EDIT: never mind, if $A$ is also a terminal object then $X$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: In fact, the coequalizer is $1$ if and only if the map $A\to 1$ is a regular epimorphism (i.e. a coequalizer). When there is a map $1\to A$, it is automatically a section of the map $A\to 1$, and then it is a regular epimorphism since it is split. But if you take the category of rings wth unit, then there is almost never a map $1\to A$ but the coequalizer is still $1$.