# Question about showing coequalizer for a pair of restricted projection maps defined on an equivalence relations which is also a poset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

The following question is taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

Let $E$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}$ whose two equivalence classes are "even" and "odd".  Note that $E$ is a poset via $(n, m)\leq (n',m')$ iff $n\leq n'$ and $m\leq m'$ such that the restricted projections $p,q: E\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are order-preserving.  Show that $coeq(p,q)$ exists in $\textbf{Poset,}$ and is not the same as in $\textbf{Set}$.

$\textbf{What I would like to know are the following:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ Since the equivalence relation consists of only two equivalence classes:  even and odd; does that mean in either of the two equivalence classes, say "even", all of $m,n, m',n'$ have all to be even, similarly for the case odd.

$\textbf{(2)}$ How do the restricted projections $p,q$ work in practice?  Is it like $p_1(n,m)=n$, $p_2(n',m')=n'$ and $q_1(n,m)=m$ $q_2(n',m')=m'$ with $(n,m)\leq(n',m')$ implying $p_1(n,m)\leq p_2(n',m')$ and $q_1(n,m)\leq q_2(n',m'),$ where $\leq$ denotes usual inequality and only applies to pairs of order pairs, $(n, m), (n',m')$, iff all $m,n, m',n'$ have the same parity. Obviously this is order preserving.  But is this the correct way to construct the projection maps?

$\textbf{(3)}$ To construct the coequalizer for this pair of projection, do I use the solution from the following [post,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635544/what-is-the-coequalizer-of-a-pair-of-projections) (I actually don't know how to apply it) or do I just do something like the following:

Let the map $h:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}/E$.  As an example if $n\leq n'$, then $h(p_1(n,m), p_2(n',m'))=0$ if $n, n'$ are both even else, $h(p_1(n,m), p_2(n',m'))=1$ if $n, n'$ are both odd. Similar construction for the case where $h(q_1,q_2).$

$\textbf{(4)}$ Lastly what does it mean that the coequalizer for this particular $\textbf{Poset}$ is not the same as in $\textbf{Set}$?

Can someone explain some of my confusions and also check on my ideas about how to go about solving this problem and if my notations and understanding of the problems are correct.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(1) No: $(n,m)\in E$ means $n$ and $m$ have the same parity. So $(n,m)\leq(n',m')$ means that $n$ and $m$ have the same parity, $n'$ and $m'$ have the same parity (possibly different from that of $n$ and $m$, and that $n\leq n'$ and $m\leq m'$.

(2) This is the correct way to construct the restricted projection maps. They are the compositions of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with the inclusion $E\hookrightarrow\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. Note that, in accordance with my correction of (1), the inequality only applies to pairs of ordered pairs $(n,m)$  and $(m',n')$ where $n$ and $m$ have the same parity, and $n'$ and $m'$ have the same parity, but possibly different from that of $n$ and $m$.

For (3) and (4), note that a function $f\colon N\to X$ to a (po)set $X$ coequalizes the projection maps $E\rightrightarrows N$ if $f(n)=f(m)$ for every pair of numbers $(n,m)$ that are both odd or both even.

In the case of sets, this is the only condition, and thus such functions $f$ correspond to functions $g\colon N/E\to X$ where $N/E$ is the set of equivalence classes of $E$, i.e. the set of two elements: the set of even numbers, and the set of odd numbers. More precisely, if $q\colon N\to N/E$ is the function sending any even number to the subset of all even numbers, and any odd number to the subset of all odd numbers, then $f\colon N\to X$ coequalizes the pair of restricted projections $E\rightrightarrows N$ if and only if $f$ factors as $f=g\circ q$ for a unique function $g\colon N/E\to X$.
Thus, $q\colon N\to N/E$ is the coequalizer of $E\rightrightarrows N$ in the category of sets.

In the case of posets, the fact that $f\colon N\to X$ is a morphism of posets means that $f(x)\leq f(y)$ if $x\leq y$. In partuclar $f(x)\leq f(x+1)\leq f(x+2)=f(x)$, where the last equality holds because $x$ and $x+2$ have the same parity, i.e. $(x,x+2)\in E$. Thus, we have $f(x)=f(x+1)$ for all $N$, i.e. $f\colon N\to X$ is constant. Since any constant function is a morphism of posets, and since constant functions are the ones that factor (necessarily uniquely) through singletons, we can conclude that any function $\top\colon N\to\{*\}$ to a singleton $\{*\}$ poset is the coequalizer of $E\rightrightarrows N$ in the category of posets.

Comment: thank you for the detail write up and my apologies for the late reply.  I just want to have few quick questions to ask in regards to your answer if that is okay.  First is, the question only require that the coequalizer function be constructed, but does it require the reader to show that such a function is a coequalizer via the universal property?  Meaning via the property "$\textit{for all sets}$ $X'$, and therefore says something about the relationship between $I$ and $\textit{every set}$ $X$: namely , there is a unique map from $X$ to $I$.

Comment: my second question is, if I can trouble you with an actual example of how the coequalizer function works.  I am not sure with respect to the condition of the equivalence relation in the question, do both $(n,m)$ and $(n',m')$ have to be of the same parity.  Suppose I have $(2,4)$ and $(3,5)$, then $(2,4)\leq(3,5)$ since $2\leq 3$ and $4\leq 5$ and $(2,4)$ is even and $(3,5)$ is odd.  Let $p_1((2,4),(3,5))=(2,4)$ and $p_2((2,4),(3,5))=(3,5)$, then $f(p_1)\leq f(p_2)$, since $2\leq 3$ and $4\leq 5$...

Comment: But according to your construction, values of $f$ are compared to each other between the same elements in the same order pairs, meaning comparing $n, m$, in $(n,m)$ and not $n, n'$ where $n\in (n,m)$ and $n'\in (n',m')$. In that case, elements of $(n,m)$ have to be of the opposite parity and not the same parity as stated in the question.  Also, how does the function $f(n)\leq f(n+1)\leq f(n+2)=f(n)$ implies that $n$ and $n+2$ have the same parity implying that...

Comment: ...$f(n)=f(n+1)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ implies that $f$ is constant.works.  Does that also mean that $f(*)=a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{N}$ if $*$ is even and $f(*)=b$ for some $b\in \mathbb{N}$ if $*$ is even.