# Question needed for clarification of notation in definition and specific term in an exercise from Arbib and Manes' basic category theory text

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, notation

The following question is taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

$\textbf{9  Definition:}$    For fixed $B$. consider the class $\textbf{M}(B)$ of all $(A,f)$ with $f:A\rightarrow B$ a monomorphism.  Say that $(A,f)\sim (A',f')$ if there exits $t:A\rightarrow A'$ with $f'\cdot t=f$ and $u$ with $f\cdot u=f'$.  It is obvious that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\textbf{M}(B)$.  An equivalence class $[A,f]$ is called a $\textbf{mono-subobject}$ of $B.$

$\textbf{11  Proposition:}$   On the category $\textbf{Vect}$
(i) $f$ is an epimorphism iff $f$ is onto iff $f$ is a coequalizer.
(ii) $f$ is an monomorphism iff $f$ is one-to-one iff $f$ is a equalizer.

$\textbf{Exercise: }$  Using $\textbf{11, }$ prove that for $B$ in $\textbf{Vect}$, mono-sub-objects of $B$ may be identified with subspaces of $B$.  [Hint: Start by completing the proof (following 9) of the corresponding result in $\textbf{Set}$]

$\textbf{Questions: }$  I just have three quick questions.

$\textbf{(1)}$ in the definition above,  The notation:  $(A,f)$, does it mean the set of all maps $f:A\rightarrow B$?

$\textbf{(2)}$ The set of equivalence classes $[A,f]$ on $\sim$ in set builder notation is $[A,f]=\{(A',f')|(A',f')\sim (A,f)\}$ and the quotient set in set builder notation is written as $\textbf{M}(B)/\sim=\{[A,f]|(A,f)\in \textbf{M}(B)\}.$ But to write out explictly each each set of equivalence classes in set builder notation, do I write it like this: $[A,f]=\{(t:A\rightarrow A', u:A\rightarrow A')|f'\cdot t=f \wedge f\cdot u=f'\}.$

$\textbf{(3)}$ What does it mean to say that a "mono-sub-objects of $B$ may be $\textbf{identified}$ with subspaces of $B$?"

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `\mid` instead of `|` for the vertical line separator when typing sets. It adds additional space which makes reading the formula easier. Compare $\{x|\phi(x)\}$ using `|` with $\{x\mid\phi(x)\}$ using `\mid`.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah kk.  Thank you.  I never knew what the differences are between the two.

Comment: It's the second item in [this part of the MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/742).

Comment: Also: do not use MathJax to typeset regular text in boldface or italics (as you do above with **Proposition**, **Exercise**, **Questions**. You can typeset bold face by using writing it between two asterisks, and italics with one. So `**Bold Text**` produces **Bold Text**, and `*italics here*` produces *italics here*.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. $\mathbf{M}(B)$ is the set of all monomorphisms with codomain $B$. The pair $(A,f)$ is a way of identifying both the monomorphism $f$ and its domain $A$ (you already know the codomain is $B$, because $(A,f)$ is an element of $\mathbf{M}(B)$.
2. Ugh. No. $[A,f]$ is a set whose elements are ordered pairs of the form $(A',f')$ satisfying certain conditions. What you write is a set whose elements are ordered pairs of the form $(t,u)$ where $t$ and $u$ are both maps... which is not at all what you have.
   $$[A,f]=\{(A',f')\mid (f'\colon A'\to B\text{ is a monomorphism})\wedge(\exists t\colon A\to A'(f'u = f))\}.$$
3. It means that every mono-sub-object of $B$ corresponds to a subspace, every subspace is a mono-sub-object, and these identifications are inverses of each other.

Comment: for 2, do you mean there exist a $t:A\rightarrow A' (f''\cdot t=f)?$, and for 3, in mathematical notation, what does it mean that every mono-subobject of $B$ corresponds to a subspace.

Comment: @Seth: I mean what I wrote. Where did the $f''$ come from? $f'u$ is shorthand for $f'\circ u$, yes. If $(A,f)$ is a mono-subobject of the vector space $B$, verify that $f(A)$ is a subspace of $B$ and that for every $(A',f')\in [A,f]$, $f'(A') = f(A)$ is the same subspace. Conversely, if $B'$ is a subspace of $B$ and $\iota\colon B'\hookrightarrow B$ is the canonical embedding, verify that $(B',\iota)\in\mathbf{M}(B)$ and that $[B',\iota]$ is precisely the collection of all $(A,f)$ with $f(A)=B'$.

Comment: can I trouble you with a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629309/question-about-showing-coequalizer-for-a-pair-of-restricted-projection-maps-defi) I recently posted.  I just have a few quick questions and I am hoping someone would provide some clarifications.  There is a lot going on in that question, and I am really having hard time with the correct notations and confusion over some of the terms used.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Seth: I really, really, *really* dislike comments in question A saying "Hey, can you take a look at question B?" So... no.

Comment: @ArthuroMagidin thank you for clarifying it for me.  If you can't read my other question. That is fine.  :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Question B has also already been answered well