# Correct commutative diagrams and other needed clarifications for an exercises on coequalizer and coproduct from Arbib and Manes' text

Tags: category-theory, coproduct

The following are taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

Let $\textbf{K}$ be the 4-object 9-morphism category

Digram 1

[image: Diagram 1]

i.e. the morphisms are $id_A$, $id_B$, $id_C$, $a,b,c,d$ and $c\circ a=c\circ b.$ Show that $C=B+D$ but that the coproduct injection $c$ is not a monomorphism. Show that whenever $A=\coprod A_i$ in a category $\textbf{L}$, a sufficient condition for ${in}_j:A_j\rightarrow A$ to be a split monomorphism is that there exists a morphism from $A_j$ to $A_i$ for all $ i.$

Also, here is the definition of coproduct for a general category:

$\text{Definition:}$ A $\textbf{coproduct}$ of $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ is a family 
$$(A_i \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{in}}_i} A\mid i\in I)$$
(of $\textbf{injections}$ which, consider in $\textbf{K}^{op}$
$$(A_i \xleftarrow{\normalsize{\text{in}}_i} <A|\in I)$$
is a product there; that is, given $f_i:A_i\rightarrow C$ there exists a unique $f:A\rightarrow C$ such that

[image]

$f\circ {in}_i=f_i$ for all $i$.  We write $A=\coprod_{i\in I} A_i$ and if $I=\{1,\ldots, n\},$ $A=A_i + \ldots + A_n.$

Also the last part of the question where the authors ask the reader the reader to "show that whenever $A=\coprod A_i$ in a category $\textbf{L}$, a sufficient condition for ${in}_j:A_j\rightarrow A$ to be a split monomorphism is that there exists a morphism from $A_j$ to $A_i$ for all $ i".$  Also, I am not sure if the following exercise as a consequences of the following theorem is relevant: (taken from Comprehensive mathematics for computer scientists vol 1, by Guerino Mazzola, ‎Gérard Milmeister, ‎Jody Weissmann)

> **Theorem:**  (Universal property of coproduct)  Given two sets $a$ and $b$ and any set $c$, the function
>
> $$\gamma:Set(a\sqcup b,c)\xrightarrow{\cong} Set(a,c)\times Set(b,c)$$
> Defined by $\gamma(u)=(u\circ {in}_a,u\circ {in}_{b})$ is a bijection.
> Proof: Clearly, a map $u:a\sqcup b\rightarrow c$ is determined by its restrictions to its partitioning subsets $\{0\}\times a$ and $\{1\}\times b$, which in turn is equivalent to the pair $u\circ {in}_{a}$ and $u\circ {in}_{b}$ of maps.  So $\gamma$ is injective.  Conversely, if $v:a\rightarrow c$ and $w:b\rightarrow c$ are any two functions, then we define $u((0,x))=v(x)$ and $u((1,y))=w(y)$, which shows the surjectivity of $\gamma$.
>
> $\textbf{Exercise:}$  Suppose that a seq $q$. together with two functions $i_a:a\rightarrow q$ and $i_b:b\rightarrow q$ has the property that
> $$\gamma:Set(q,c)\xrightarrow{\cong} Set(a,c)\times Set(b,c)$$
> defined by $\gamma(u)=(u\circ i_a,u\circ i_b)$ is a bijection.  Show that there is a unique bijection $i:a\sqcup b\rightarrow q$ such that $i\circ {in}_a=i_a,i\circ {in}_b=i_b.$

Lastly from $\textit{Handbook of Categorical Algebra 1: Basica Category theory}$ by F Borceux, he provides a general definition for Coproduct in a general category along with associated propositions:

[image]

[image]

$\textbf{Questions:}$

I have few quick questions about the above exercise.

(1) For showing that $C=B+D$, is the following commutative diagram correct?  I am not sure if I need to draw a pushout diagram in order to solve the problem.  Also, not sure what role $c$ being the coequalizer is to play in $C$ is the coproduct of $B+D$.

[image]

(2) Should not the coproduct injection $c$ be a monomorphism.  The reason for being such is that if $c$ is a coequalizer, then it implies that $a=b?$ Basically, is there a misprint to this part of the question.

(3) I added the relevant information about $A=\coprod A_J$ and ${in}_j:A_j\rightarrow A$ to the second commutative diagram above, but where should a morphism from $A_j$ to $A_i$ for all $i$ be placed in the commutative diagram below.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$:

Usually $B+D$ is notation for $B\sqcup D$, so your diagram doesn't make sense in that respect. Otherwise, your diagram is correct, but probably confusing for you. All you have to do is check that $(c:B\to C,d:D\to C,C)$ is a coproduct for $B$ and $D$ - so just check the universal property. In my experience, it's rarely easier or helpful to check: "Is the canonical arrow $B\sqcup D\to C$ an isomorphism?" and it's especially unhelpful here since *a priori* you don't even know that $B\sqcup D$ exists.

The universal property involves arrows *out* of $C$. Are there any?

$(2)$:

The whole point of this exercise is to point out coproduct inclusions don't have to be monomorphisms. It *is* true that $c$ is a coequaliser, but they didn't actually say that in the text. Just in case, I think I should ask you (or you should ask yourself) to check $c$ is a coequaliser in detail i.e. you should check the universal property is satisfied.

That being said, coequalisers are not guaranteed to be monomorphisms. In most of the usual categories such as $\mathsf{Set},\mathsf{Ab},\mathsf{Top}$ etc. coequalisers are hardly ever monomorphisms (monic(s)). They are *epimorphisms* (epic(s)), but 'epis' aren't guaranteed to be 'monos'. It is not true that $a=b$, and there is no misprint at all.

What is the definition of monomorphism? Does it apply when tested against the arrow $c$?

(I think I might recommend to you in general, that exercises in category theory tend to be solved just by "unwinding the definitions" i.e. just figure out what on Earth you have to check, explicitly, and once you've done that things become a hellavalot easier).

$(3)$:

I don't know why you've drawn that diagram, it'll only confuse you. You're supposed to check this for an *arbitrary* category $\mathsf{L}$.

Hint: To check $\mathrm{in}_j:A_j\to A$ is a 'split mono' (get used to the abbreviations, I'd advise) we just need to find some arrow $s_j:A\to A_j$ with $s\circ\mathrm{in}_j=\mathrm{Id}_{A_j}$, by definition.

How do we get an arrow $A\to A_j$? Well, arrows *out* of coproducts ($A$ being a coproduct) have quite an explicit description. Let's use that to *construct* the $s_j$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143150/discussion-on-answer-by-fshrike-correct-commutative-diagrams-and-other-needed-cl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @FShrike for the first part, showing that $C=B+D$, Let $B=B', D=D'$, and we want to show that $B+D$ is a coproduct of $B'\times D'$.  Let $B'\times \{1\}=\{(b_1,1)\mid b_1\in B'\}$, $D'\times \{2\}=\{(d_2,2)\mid d_2 \in D'\}$ and we define the injective maps: ${in}_1:B'\rightarrow B'\sqcup D':b_1\mapsto (b_1,1)$ and ${in}_2:D'\rightarrow B'\sqcup D':d_1\mapsto (d_2,2).$  Since$c:B\rightarrow B+D$ and $d:D\rightarrow B+D$, then given any set $C,$ there exists a $f:B'\sqcup D'\rightarrow C:(b_1,1)\mapsto c(b_1)$ or $f(b_1,1)=c(b_1)$ and $f:B'\sqcup D'\rightarrow C: (d_2,2)\mapsto d(d_2)$ or ....

Comment: @FShrike ...If $f':B'\sqcup D'\rightarrow C$ is another map where $f'(b_1,1)=c(b_1)$ and $f'(d_2,2)=d(d_2)$, then $f(b_1,1)=f'(b_1,1)=c(b_1)$ and $f(d_2,2)=f'(d_2,2)=d(d_2).$  Hence $f=f'$ which makes $f$ unique.

Comment: @FShrike for $$ as coequalizers. Suppose $c$ coequalizes the pair of maps $a$ and $b,$ meaning $∘=∘.$ Also suppose ${}_1$ is another map where ${}_1∘={}_1∘.$ Then there exists a unique $$ so that $∘=∘$ and $∘={}_1$. This "$∘=∘$," satisfies the antecedent of the definitional statement for monomorphism, so it should imply that $a=b$? I must be missing something subtle here. Also, I still don't understand why the coproduct injections are not mono-morphisms and...

Comment: @FShrike ...I still don't know how to do the question for showing the sufficient condition for split monomorphism for a arbitrary category $\textbf{L}.$

Comment: @Seth Why are you talking about $B’,D’$ rather than $B,D$? You don’t want to show $B+D$ is the coproduct of $B’\times D’$, and that doesn’t even make sense. You take coproducts of two or more things, not just one object on its own ($B’\times D’$). You want in particular to show $C$ is a coproduct of $B$ and $D$, and you’ve not said anything related to that. You’ve used the standard construction of coproducts in $\mathsf{Set}$… but this is not $\mathsf{Set}$. You cannot talk about elements $b_1\in B$ either.

Comment: @Seth If I’m going to nitpick then I’ll also say “since $c:B\to B+D$…” doesn’t make sense. You use $c$ as an arbitrary map $B\to C$ where “$C$ is any set”. It also wouldn’t be a good use of “since” as no deduction is really made.

Comment: In short, you’ve gone off on a tangent. I strongly recommend you read back through my discussion of $(1)$ and think about the last sentence there.

Comment: For the business with $\mathsf{L}$, come back to me after you’ve had a thought about what I said in $(3)$, consider the hint.

Comment: @FShrike I thought I am suppose to apply the coproduct construction from the category of $\textbf{Sets}$.  By the way, do you have access to the book of Arbib and Manes, it is on library genesis.  I am just using how he defined coproduct..  It is only later that I found out it is only for the category of $\textbf{Sets}.$  I am very much trying to stick to that text only, even though at times, i have to consult other sources for a better definition.  Another thing is I am still not clear about how $c$ is not a monomorphism even though $c$ plays a role in the coproduct construction.

Comment: About the coequalisers. This is *not*, “meaning $ca=cb$”. A coequaliser has the extra universal property. Then you say “there is a unique $\phi$ with $\phi a=\phi b$” but that’s not what the universal property says. It says, there is unique $\phi$ that $\phi c=\mathrm{in}_1$. I don’t know what you mean about satisfying the antecedent, this is a logical mistake. $ca=cb$ doesn’t imply $a=b$, and it is false in this case. $c$ isn’t a monic.

Comment: @Seth No, you are supposed to apply the definition of coproduct in an arbitrary category (= universal property). You can’t appeal to sets since this isn’t a category of sets. It is also the point of the exercise, that $c$ can be a coproduct ‘inclusion’ but not actually be a monomorphism. See my discussion in $(2)$

Comment: With all due respect I again get the impression you haven’t really tried to properly read my answer. Please try to ask focused questions, when you have any, avoid repeating the same misconceptions

Comment: @FShrike I just look up Horst Shubert's Categories on page 45 exercise 6.6.5 (a), it states that "A functor $T:C\rightarrow D$ is a monomorphism in $\textit{Cat}$ if and only if $T$ is an embedding. So since $c$ as a map is a coequalizer and not an embedding (inclusion map), hence the map $c$ is not a monomorphism.  Is that correct?  Also, for (1), i am using the coproduct construction for category of $\textbf{Sets}$ but in Arbib and Manes' text, it assumes that the reader knows how to use the universal property to show uniqueness.  The book doesn't talk....

Comment: @FShrike ...the book doesn't talk about if the definition of coproduct along with its associated universal property are defined differently for a general abstract category.  :(

Comment: @Seth Define ‘embedding’. This isn’t an argument, *especially because* you’re talking about *functors* as monic arrows in the category of all small categories. Since we aren’t in that category (!!) you can’t use results like that. $c$ is not a monomorphism for a much, much, much simpler reason. Please, again, see my own discussion about this. **Don’t** use the construction for coproducts in $\mathsf{Set}$, this is not a category of sets. The general definition of coproduct is easily found online. One way, it is the colimit of the diagram $\mathbb{2}\to\mathsf{K}$, $0\mapsto B,1\mapsto D$.

Comment: @FShrike sorry, I thought that there might be an equivalent results apply to the case for coequalizers, where if it an embedding, then, it can be concluded that it is a monomorphism.  Also, what are the 2, 0, and 1, in the domains of your three morphisms? And how are the three morphisms describe coproduct?

Comment: @Seth In a general category there isn’t really a concept of ‘embedding’. $\mathbb{2}$ is notation for the discrete category on two elements, say, the objects are $0$ and $1$ and the only arrows are identities. Then the functor $F:\mathbb{2}\to\mathsf{K}$ that takes the object $0$ to $B$ and $1$ to $D$ has the property: the coproduct $B+D$ exists iff. the colimit of $F$ exists, and in this case $\operatorname{colim} F\cong B+D$ will be true. So we can use such $F$ in the *definition* of coproduct, and this is equivalent to all other definitions

Comment: My apologies. On my phone, the $2$ was supposed to render in a different font, similar to $\mathbf{2}$ (to distinguish it from $0$ and $1$). For whatever reason, this other font isn't appearing on the website.

Comment: @FShrike  For (a) I added the definition/construction for coproduct for a general category from Arbib and Manes' text.  As for (b), As for (b) taken from $\textit{Theory of Mathematical Structures}$ by Jirk Adamek: $\text{Proposition 1:}$  Let $C$ be a construct which has a free object on one generator.  Then a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a mono iff the map $f$ is one-to one. $\text{Proposition 2:}$ Each Coretraction is a monomorphism. So either the coequalizer $c$ is either not injective or it is not a coretraction/section.  I don't know if it is true or how to show that a coequalizer...

Comment: @FShrike ...a coequalizer is not a coretraction/section..   Also, should not be the ${in}_1$,${in}_2$ maps be the coproduct injection maps instead of $c$?

Comment: @Seth I don't want to say it again! Forget all about "injections" and retractions and so on. You're drowning in fancy categorical language but you need to focus on the absolute basics right now: learn the definition of monomorphism, and check whether or not it applies to $c$ (as I have said many times). Don't delve into the deeps of categorical literature, you're only confusing yourself. It is true that every retract is epic, every coretract is monic, but that's really overcomplicating the situation.

Comment: You're not in a set-like category so words like "injection" (typically referring to functions between sets...) should be avoided. Is it true that $cf=cg\implies f=g$ for all arrows $f,g$ which can compose with $c$? Yes or no? That is all you have to check

Comment: @FShrike well the question never stated thst the maps $a,b$ are equal.  I am not sure if that is a proof or an argument.  Also, is the added general definition for the coproduct in my post apply to a general category?

Comment: @Seth That general definition is the correct definition… except **don’t call them injections when they aren’t necessarily functions**. Remember one of the objectives of this exercise is to prove the coproduct ‘inclusions’ $\mathrm{in}_i$ don’t need to be monomorphisms (“injections”). And yes! $a,b$ are not equal. So by very definition, $ca=cb$ with $a\neq b$ automatically implies $c$ is not monic!!

Comment: See how much simpler that was than all this ‘embedding’, ‘coretraction’ etc.? Beware the trap of overthinking

Comment: @FShrike for (1) I have not shown that $C=B+D.$  I have provide the general definition and its construction.  I can modify the definition by attaching the appropriate letters to the morphisms domain and codomain in the general definition and construction.  But other than that, does that constitute a proof.  For (3) am I asked to solve a retraction/section problem?

Comment: @Seth There is no general construction of a coproduct. There are well known ones in the classical categories, but that’s not relevant - as I’ve said before. For $(1)$ and $(3)$ I can only refer you to what I have already said in my answer. Again, it does not really feel like you’ve been reading what I wrote. Since my answer is a genuine answer, it’s a good place to start!

Comment: @FShrike for part (3) I added a quoted theorem along with an exercise as a corollary.  In that quoted exercise, it asks the author to show that the function $i:a\sqcup b\rightarrow q$ such that $i\circ {in}_a=i_a,i\circ {in}_b=i_b.$ is a unique bijection. Is the function $i$ in that exercise the function part (3) asks for?

Comment: @FShrike Can I trouble you also with this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629814/question-needed-for-clarification-of-notation-in-definition-and-specific-term-in) quickly, since it has to do with notational clarifications.  In that post Arturo answered in his comments explaining to me about the various notations of the exercises in that post, when he said: "Where did the $″$ come from? $′$ is shorthand for $′\circ ,$ yes. If $(,)$ is a mono-subobject of the vector space $,$ verify that $()$ is a subspace of $$ and ...

Comment: @FShrike ...that for every $(′,′)\in [,], ′(′)=()$ is the same subspace. Conversely, if $′$ is a subspace of $$ and $:′\hookrightarrow $ is the canonical embedding, verify that $(′,)\in \textbf{}()$ and that $[′,]$ is precisely the collection of all $(,)$ with $()=′$".  I am still not clear if the way I define $\textbf{M}(B)/\sim$ as $\textbf{M}(B)/\sim=\{[A,f]|(A,f)\in \textbf{M}(B)\}.$ is correct, and also how do I define $(A,f)=\{...\},$ $\textbf{M}(B)=\{\}$ in set builder notations.

Comment: @Seth For the last time: please thoughtfully read what I’ve said concerning points $(1)$ and $(3)$ and - if necessary - get back to me with a question that coherently makes a *response* to what I’ve said, so we can have a constructive conversation.

Comment: @FShrike wait, the quoted exercises only applies to the category of sets.  When I included the definition from Arbib and Manes; text that doesn't apply to category of Sets, I can't really tell the differences.  I mean, the wordings are so similar with a minutiae change in either wordings or math details/notations.  I am not sure if it is my reading ability, or if it is I am learning it on my own and I don't have anyone to talk to in person. Also for $\mathrm{in}_j:A_j\to A$, am I suppose to think about completing some commutative diagram to find what the mapping $s_j$ is suppose to be?

Comment: @Seth You should be thinking about the universal property of coproducts to find a map $A\to A_j$. And I do apologise. I didn't check the theorem statement I just worked off of your quote, which talked about "unique bijection" and that rang alarm bells for me. Again, as this is an arbitrary category, the word you should be using is *isomorphism* and you should avoid set-language. However the theorem just phrases the universal property of coproduct in terms of bijections of hom-sets, so it is ok - in that respect - to use set language as (most) general categories have hom-sets.

Comment: @Seth But it's just a potentially more confusing restatement of the universal property that you already should know. My advice to you in $(3)$ was to think about this property, but let me state it in simpler terms. If you know arrows $A_j\to X$ for every $j$ then you get a unique arrow $A\to X$. Here, $X=A_i$ for some arbitrary $i$, and you want to get a special $s_i:A\to A_i$. Think about how we might *construct* such an $s$ (stop worrying about general theorems, at this point, this is a concrete exercise in a concrete category which can be solved with no generalities)

Comment: @FShrike No worries.  I included two screenshots of something from Handbook of Categorical Algebra vol 1.  The first is a definition of coproduct for a general category, the second is a proposition following it.  I included because as examples how at times category definitions and various propositions are confusingly phrased. in the sense in which mathematical lane is the reader suppose to be staying on. The other thing is, when i ask questions or search on here about category theory topics related, I keep encountering new terms.

Comment: @Seth Sure. That general definition is correct. Looking around for more definitions won't help you though, since you've already got all the ones you need. Focus on what I said and on the problem at hand. Build a map $A\to A_i$ given knowledge of the universal description of such maps.

Comment: @FShrike, for (3), is it like this:  $A_i\xrightarrow{w}A=\coprod A_j$ for $i\neq j$ and every $j$ and $A\xrightarrow{z} X$, then $A\xrightarrow{z\circ w} X$ where $z\circ w =s_j:A_j\rightarrow X$?  When you tell me to build a map., I am used to the fact that I am constructing commutative diagrams.  Not sure how close that is relate to the universal property.

Comment: @FShrike I edited my comment.  Not sure if that is correct.  I tried to respect the bit about disjoint union.  Though I am not sure if that particular property plays a part in the general definition.  I think disjoint unions take different forms depending on which category we are speaking about, is that correct?  It is a bit hard to get an intuition about the definition for a general coproduct other than for me to think in terms of elements....

Comment: @Seth Well, "disjoint" doesn't really make sense without sets but the language (disjoint) union is still sometimes used. Certainly, coproducts take different forms depending on the category you're talking about. I hope by "$w$" you mean $\mathrm{in}_i$ by the way. To define a map $A\to X=A_j$ you still need to specify component maps $A_i\to A_j$ for every $i$.

Comment: @FShrike yes $w$ is intend to stand in for ${in}_i$.  What do "component mpas" mean?

Comment: @FShrike don't $w:A_i\rightarrow \coprod A_j$ equal to $(0,\ldots,0,A_j,0,\ldots,0)$ for $i\neq j$ else, it equals to $A_i$? for every $i$, then I can compose it with $A_i\rightarrow A_j$?

Comment: @Seth Think of an arrow $f:A\to X$ as having many "components" $f\mathrm{in}_i:A_i\to X$. This is good language because we know $f$ is uniquely determined by its components

Comment: @Seth Avoid set language! $(0,\cdots,0,A_j,0,\cdots)$ doesn't really make sense here! Plus, we don't care about the $w$. Really. Only thing we need to know is that they make the universal property hold. What we do care about is specifying components. And I'm off, will say more if I need to tomorrow

Comment: @FShrike okk, I will try to think about what you said and see if I can come up with an answer, if not, I will leave a message here.  :)

Comment: @FShrike how about the following:  let $s$ be defined as $s:A_i\mapsto A_i$ and ${in}_j(A_i)=A_j$ $\text{for } i=j.$ then $s\circ {in}_j={id}_{A_j}.$

Comment: @Seth That does not make sense. You want $s:A\to A_j$, not $A_i\to A_i$. $\mathrm{in}_j(A_i)=A_j$ also doesn’t make any sense just because you’re mixing ‘types’: what do you mean by arrow(object)=object? In set based thinking that’s fine, but it’s strange to see here. I feel like I should remind you there is an additional hypothesis that there exist arrows $A_m\to A_n$ for any $n,m$. I recommend thinking about what the universal property means, again. Think about ‘component’ maps

Comment: @FShrike after looking at the exercise again, instead of defining an explicit mapping that evaluate elements, I just simply defined maps and here is what I come up with:  $A_j\xrightarrow{ {in}_j} A=\coprod A_i\xrightarrow{s} A_i,$ then we can let $A_j\xrightarrow{\phi=s\circ {in}_j} A_i$

Comment: Nono @Seth You need to define *s*. Given $s$, then that's exactly right that the components are $s\circ\mathrm{in}_j$. But you're not given $s$! You need to "make" it on your own

Comment: @FShrike I thought the map for $s$ is $\coprod A_i\rightarrow A_i,$ for every $i$?  And the $s$ map should be unique.   Also is that what you meant when you tell me to look at the universal property of the coproduct to find the hint.  Maybe I am missing something.  There are so many ways what the map $s$ is suppose to be, correct?

Comment: Uh. @Seth The map $s$ can certainly be any number of things in general however ! there is one and only one way you can construct $s$ in this exercise. $s$ does not go from $\bigsqcup A_i\to A_i$ for every $i$ ? We are fixing only one $A_\bullet$, let's say $A_n$, and $s:\bigsqcup_{i\in I}A_i\to A_n$ is some special map that still needs to be constructed. Looking at the universal property is the *only* way to construct $s$ here. To paraphrase Tom Leinster, "if you're stuck on an exercise it's likely you don't understand the definitions." "Unwinding" definitions solves most exercises.

Comment: And this realisation helped me greatly when doing the exercises in his book. Since everything is so general, the only things I really can know are the statements given to me, and everything should "definitionally" fit together in one and only one way. Doing exercises in other subjects, you must struggle with many different approaches and ideas. In introductory category theory there is generally only one "possible" thing to do and it reveals itself after you understand what the definition tells you. The restricted knowledge (great generality) actually makes it easier

Comment: @FShrike Okay, I used the universal mapping property from the definition of coproduct for a general category.  This is what I have:  From the definition of coproduct for a general category, given $f_i:A_i\rightarrow C$ there exists a unique $f:A\rightarrow C$ such that $f\circ {in}_i=f_i$ for all $i$.  $A=\coprod_{i\in I} A_i.$   So we have $A_j \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{in}}_j} A$, then we can let $A=\coprod_{i\in I} A_i,$ and let $C=A_j,$ for some $j\in I,$ and the morphism $i:A\rightarrow A_j$ such that $i\circ {in}_j=i_j,$ where $i_j:A_j\rightarrow A_j.$

Comment: @Seth But you haven’t told me what $i_j$ is or even what $i$ is. You can’t just ‘let’ $i$ you need to specify it somehow. That’s the correct universal property definition but you haven’t really applied it.

Comment: @FShrike, I just modify the universal property as needed to get the requisite morphisms.  I thought that is what you meant by thinking about the universal mapping property.

Comment: @Seth Well, kind of. You do need to think about it but you should realise why you haven’t actually used it correctly here. Your goal is to build an arrow $i$, or $s$, $A\to A_j$. The property tells you exactly what you need to build such an arrow, and you don’t have that / haven’t used that. I don’t want to explicitly say what it is you’re missing because it will probably ruin the whole thing. All you’ve done is say, ok, we can apply the universal property to $A$ and use a target of $C=A_j$. But you need to say how to use the property (‘feed it’ the right data). “$i$“ comes from nowhere

Comment: Also *you haven’t used the hypothesis given in the exercise which is usually a bad sign*!

Comment: @FShrike the hypothesis says that $A=\coprod A_i$ in category $\textbf{L}...$ and $i$ is the identity morphism.  What am I suppose to do to construct the identity morphism or show that it exists.  Look I am given a family of injection maps ${in}_j$ that maps from $A_j$ to $A=\coprod A_i.$  We want a map $f$ composed with $[in]_j$ and lands back at $A_j$ for some $j$.  So the map $f$ has to go from $\coprod A_i$ to $A_j$ for some $j$.  The composition map would be equal to the identity morphism $i_j:A_j\rightarrow A_j$.  I don't know what else or what more I can say or do?

Comment: The hypothesis that is special for the exercise that you haven’t yet talked about is: “for all $i$ and $j$ there exists an arrow $A_i\to A_j$”. The map $f$ does indeed have to go $A\to A_j$. But who says such $f$ exists?? Remember, arrows $A\to A_j$ are exactly the same as families of arrows $A_i\to A_j$. You never specified such a family for your “$f$”, $f$ has just been made up out of the blue

Comment: @FShrike it has been a few days since we last spoke.  I should have clarified few things about me learning about category theory this whole time.  As far as using the universal property is concerned, I am not clear the difference between that and showing uniqueness.  I am referring to the four isomorphisms theorem from group theory as an example.  Another thing is when you say i need to construct the morphism, I thought proving something that exists, I just need to produce said thing and that it works.  I don't really have to construct it.  An example would be the existence and uniqueness....

Comment: @FShrike ...the existence and uniqueness solution for differential equations. Lastly, in the case of coequalizers, it was never really explain why there needs to be a quotienting process. I think in the case of category of sets, there is a spelled out procedure of finding the smallest equivalence relations, blah blah blah. But in the case of more general category, i often see something like /(),
 say in the case of category of vector spaces. Again, there is no motivating reasons as to why is needed.  As to the question in the exercise....

Comment: @FShrike my understanding is the morphism $A_j\xrightarrow{{in}_j} \coprod A_i$ is like a projection map, and the image of that is $A_j$, I compose $f$ with ${in}_j$ where I defined $\coprod A_i\xrightarrow{f} A_j$, I am doing a reverse projection.  I am not sure there is a proper name for plugging out a specific $A_j$ amongst all the ${A_i}s$ in $\coprod A_i$ and send it to $A_j$.  I mean the projection notation does takes care of the reverse process.  In the case of category of sets where I cited the exercises in my post, in that exercise, the way to take care of it is much easier...

Comment: @FShrike it is much easier since it allow me to use the function notation.  But I am not sure how this can be done when I can't assume we are talking about functions.

Comment: @Seth I'm going to give the answer to exercise $(3)$ now. I think you need to see concretely, I can't make roundabout hints anymore. If you're **given** the universal property then **you do not need to show uniqueness** because uniqueness *is already given*. Now, you can't "produce said thing and [show] that it works" to show it exists. You cannot produce a nonexistent thing. I'm not trying to be philosophical here, but what you've done a few days ago was logically invalid. You noted that such an $f$, or $s$, *could* exist, and *could* work. That is not enough to say that it *does* exist

Comment: For exercise $(1)$, you really don't need to think about quotienting or whatever. Just examine the universal property definition. Quotients can be hard to get your head around, but maybe I should ask you: how else would you do it? Now I'm going to pick you up on your second last comment: "I compose $f$ with $\mathrm{in}_j$ where I **defined** $\bigsqcup A_i\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}A_j$". **You did not define $f$**, you merely said a little about how you wanted it to exist. I'm going to show you what I mean in the next comment

Comment: @FShrike for (1), the uncertain part for me is, do I have to worry about the pair of morphisms $a,b:A\rightarrow B$ when I try to show $B=C+D$.  Also, the reason I am asking a billion questions on here is because I found a lot of the motivation behind why certain things are done the way they are (the ones I listed among many others), are not really explain well in many of the category theory texts.  As for coequalizers, I just don't understand why the quotienting process is necessary.  Apparently, anything with the prefix (co) in category theory tends to be more complicated.

Comment: The exercise is actually quite simple, it is a test of understanding of definitions. Given: in some category, some family of objects $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and $A:=\bigsqcup_{i\in I}A_i$ exists. We are given that for all pairs $(n,m)\in I^2$ there is an arrow $f_{n,m}:n\to m$ in the category. Want to show: for any $j$ there exists $s:A\to A_j$ with $s\cdot\mathrm{in}_j=\mathrm{Id}_{A_j}$. Proof: pick $j\in I$. The arrows $\mathrm{Id}_j:A_j\to A_j,\,(f_{i,j}:A_i\to A_j)_{i\in I}$ are a family of arrows from the $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ to $A_j$. (cont.)

Comment: The universal property gives us ("constructs") an arrow $s:A\to A_j$ with: $$s\cdot\mathrm{in}_i=\begin{cases}f_{i,j}&i\neq j\\\mathrm{Id}_j&i=j\end{cases}$$For all $i\in I$. In particular $s\cdot\mathrm{in}_j=\mathrm{Id}_j$ exactly as we want.

Comment: The $f_{n,m}$ are *absolutely essential*. You never once told me what you thought $s\cdot\mathrm{in}_i$ should be for $i\neq j$ - *you never defined $s$*.

Comment: @FShrike this is not necessary for this post, but I don't understand the purpose of having universal property in definitions versus regular isomorphisms or showing uniqueness.  Yes, I know that universal mapping property is showing something is unique up to unique isomorphism. But in the case of various isomorphism theorem in algebras, it is just unique up to isomorphism.  In algebra, the issue of whether something can have multiple isomorphism and they may not be equivalent/equal amongst all the other isomorphisms, that is not discussed at all.

Comment: @FShrike  Oh I see what you meant by component maps, you meant maps index by $i$.  I tried to capture how you try to do it in our back and forth.  I think the map that you define is like a reverse projection.

Comment: @Seth https://discord.com/invite/eWz73MCpHs . I put the link here because it is not so publicly visible. Discord is a very popular social media type app, **not** in the sense of instagram or whatever, it is quite a bit different. Essentially it is a whole bunch of chatrooms

Comment: @Ah okay okay. Thanks.  I will check it out over the weekend.  :)

Comment: https://discord.gg/CRfAXYNnfa is a much larger one (generally discussing quite a bit more advanced things, most of the people there are quite intimidating with their knowledge)