# Question about an exercise on showing why the colimit for Poset as a category can not be constructed in Arbib and Manes text

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

The following question is taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

$\text{(1):}$ Given a relation ${\stackrel{\small{R}\stackrel{\small\small p_1}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\small{A}}{\small\small p_2}}{\stackrel{\stackrel{}{\stackrel{}{}}{}}{}},$  we can define the $\textbf{the equivalence relation generated by}$ $(R,p_1,p_2)$ to be $\bar{R}$, the smallest equivalence relation containing the relation defined by $R:(a,a')\in \bar{R}$ iff either $a=a'$ or $(a,a')$ can be linked by a chain $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{n+1})$ of elements of $A$ where $a=a_1,a'=a_{n+1}$ and for each $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n,$ either $(a_k, a_{k+1}) \text{ or } (a_{k+1},a_i)$ belongs to $E_R,$ where $E_R=\{(p_1(r), p_2(r))\mid r\in R\}\subset A\times A,$ and $p_k:R\rightarrow A:(a_1,a_2)\mapsto a_k, k=1,2.$

$\text{19 Corollary:}$   The colimit of any diagram $D$ in $\textbf{Set}$ is obtained as follow.  Consider the disjoint union $\coprod D_i=\{(d,i)\mid d\in D_i\}.$  Let $R$ be the subset

$$\{(d,i;d',i')\mid \exists e:i\rightarrow i' \text{with } D_e(d)=d' \}$$

of $\coprod D_i \times \coprod D_i$ and let $\bar{R}$ be the equivalence relation generated by $R$ as in $(1)$.  Let $\gamma_i:D_j\rightarrow (\coprod D_i)/R, d\mapsto [d,j].$  Then $((\coprod D_i)/R,(\gamma_j))$ is the colimit of $D.$

Exercise 3.2: Let $E$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}$ whose two equivalence classes are "even" and "odd".  Note that $E$ is a poset via $(n, m)\leq (n',m')$ iff $n\leq n'$ and $m\leq m'$ such that the restricted projections $p,q: E\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are order-preserving.  Show that $coeq(p,q)$ exists in $\textbf{Poset,}$ and is not the same as in $\textbf{Set}$.

post: [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629309/question-about-showing-coequalizer-for-a-pair-of-restricted-projection-maps-defi) which was answered by Vladimir Sotirov

> $\textbf{Use exercise 3.2:}$ to conclude that the analogous construction to $\text{19 Corollary}$ does not construct colimits of diagrams in $\text{Poset}.$

My $\textbf{question}$ is, the reason for the colimit $\textbf{Poset}$ can't be constructed, is it because the Poset in exercise 3.2 don't have an initial object or because the coproduct for the Poset in rhat exercise don't exists?  But coequalizer for that Poset and also coproduct are considered as colimit.  The text I am using have no theorems for criterias when limits/colimits can or can not be constructed.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise is unclear - it all depends on what "analogous" means.

[According to nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pos), the category of posets is cocomplete. Hence, all colimits exist and all coproducts and coequalisers exist. So quite literally, the coproduct-coequaliser construction (which is "analogous" in that it is the same for every category which can compute it) computes all colimits.

I am then guessing they don't mean for the "analogy" to be in terms of coproducts and coequalisers, but rather in terms of the setwise coproduct and the equivalence relation quotient. But this doesn't quite make sense, since, although you'll compute a *set*, you're not immediately computing a *poset*. So what they *really* mean is this:

> Show that (or, just appreciate the fact that) the forgetful functor $U:\mathsf{Poset}\to\mathsf{Set}$ does **not** preserve colimits.

As for your comments, I'm sorry to say they don't really make sense. You're interchanging "poset" (just, the literal thing, a set with a certain ordering) with the category of all posets.

> "...is it because the Poset in exercise 3.2 don't have an initial/terminal object?"

Well, although you *can* view individual posets as categories in their own right, here you're asking about the category of *all* posets, so what it means to have a colimit is very different. Also, even if initial and terminal objects don't exist (which, by the way, they *do* in the category of all posets) that doesn't mean a particular colimit won't exist, it just means: "not all colimits exist".

If you just want a general reason, **not** for: "why don't all colimits exist?" (because they apparently do!) but rather for: "why don't all colimits in $\mathsf{Poset}$ look like the corresponding colimits in $\mathsf{Set}$?"

Then my explanation is: the universal properties for $\mathsf{Poset}$ require the unique maps to also be *monotone*, which means that we can't just take the same quotients that we take in $\mathsf{Set}$: how do you order the quotient set? Well, you use some ordering generated by all the quotient maps but this is quite complicated and, importantly, *may make some additional identifications* (by that I mean, where in $\mathsf{Set}$ we may have two different equivalence classes $a$ and $b$, we might find that $b\ge a\le b$ is forced hence $a=b$...) so this is a more 'aggressive' process, and produces different quotient objects then are produced in $\mathsf{Set}$.

A concrete example of this is exactly as in Vlad's answer. The $\mathsf{Set}$-quotient $\Bbb N/E$ has two elements, let's call them $0,1$ to refer to the even and odd classes respectively. As $2\le 3\le 4$ in $\Bbb N$ (these are random numbers) it is actually forced that $0\le 1\le 0$ ($2\sim0$ because it is even, etc.) hence $1=0$ - so there are no longer two distinct equivalence classes, there is only one. A new "identification" has been made.

Comment: the concept of functor and forgetful functor don't get introduced until four more chapters later.  Also, the text haven't really talk about which categories preserves which other categories, like forgetful functors preserves colimits.

Comment: @Seth You don’t need to have studied functors yet. All that what I said means is that, if you have a colimit in the category of posets, and then you look at the underlying set of that colimit, it won’t necessarily be a colimit of the underlying diagram of sets. Example: the one point set is not the two point set (see Vlad’s answer).

Comment: the forgetful functor $U:\mathsf{Poset}\to\mathsf{Set}$ that you suggested; I asked Dr Google and it says that to show a forgetful functor that don't preserves colimits, show that it does not have an adjoint/left adjoins. (One of the two, not clear on which at this point)  Anyways, the notion of adjoins or related concepts don't come up a few chapters after the one this question appears in.  Might there be some other interpretation to the question that don't require me to consult ahead?

Comment: @Seth Ignore adjoints for now! Like I said, I only mentioned forgetful functors in order to have a precise language to describe what I was saying. However, I repeat a completely equivalent statement in my most recent comment. "All that what I said means is that, if you have a colimit ...": *that* is your Dr Google for the day. It is true that *a* method (*applicable only under some conditions*) to show something isn't cocontinuous is to show it doesn't have a **right** adjoint. However, that's (a) way too powerful for now and (b) you already have an example of a colimit $U$ doesn't preserve!

Comment: what does it mean for a category not to preserve "some other category", like colimit, coproduct, etc?  I am noticing in category theory, there are like a million other new terms used for every concept I try to understand.

Comment: @Seth I have never seen “preserve a category” except in your comments. You can say, preserve *colimits*, or something like that. You’re getting too hung up on my choice of language, I feel. What I said was just a way to describe what the exercise wants to get at: “show that colimits in the category of posets do not ‘look like’ colimits in the category of sets”.

Comment: when you say "do not look like", you mean I should look up what the colimits for the category of Posets look like, then try to determine what the corresponding colimit look like for the particular Poset in exercise 3.2? One of my category theory texts I have lying around describes what colimit of Poset is.  Another thing is, I thought the question might be asking to show that the existence of colimits for the poset in ex 3.2 can't be constructed because it violate some theorems or definition such as whether it has finite colimits or some criteria for existence of colimits, etc.

Comment: @Seth I mean this. If you have a colimit $F$ of some diagram $D$ of posets, in Poset, then $F$ is a poset and in particular it has an underlying set, call it $G$ for clarity. If you consider the same diagram $D$ in Set and take its colimit in Set, this will be some set $H$. The claim is that the $G$ is not isomorphic to $H$ in general (actually, the claim is a bit more than that, but let's keep things simple). Example? Well, Vlad's answer... we found that $G$ was a singleton but $H$ was a two element set, so they are not the same

Comment: *And what this means*, is that you can't build colimits in the category of posets just by building the colimit in the category of sets and then giving this set some ordering. I am fairly certain this is what your authors meant by "the analogous construction fails", but it's poor from them to phrase it like that since (as I have already said) it all depends on how you interpret "analogous"

Comment: i tried emailing either authors, one of them told me that I should go find friends or people online to help me sort out any difficulties with the text since it is so long since he wrote the text.  The other author, his email no longer works anymore.  Let me think about your explanation.  If I have any more difficulties, I will leave a comment here.  Also, thank you for taking the time to answer my billion different questions.  :)

Comment: i was just looking at the other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629309/question-about-showing-coequalizer-for-a-pair-of-restricted-projection-maps-defi) that you were commenting on here about coming up with coequalizer for Poset.  I am wondering can you explain when Vlad saids that the function $f$ in the end being a constant.  Is it suppose to some sort of arbitrary value in the underlying field that the Poset is defined on.  Also, what did you mean by for the case of $G$, it is of only of a singleton and but for $H$, it is of only two element set....

Comment: how did you came up with that.  I just want to make sure I am on the same page as you.  Thank you in advance

Comment: @Seth I mean $G$ is literally just a singleton set (only has one element) and $H$ is literally just a two-element set. As for the first, “underlying field?” Posets don’t have underlying fields, that’s a term from (linear) algebra. They do have underlying sets though. And when Vlad says $f$ must be a constant function they just mean, for some element $x\in X$ (we don’t know or care which element it is) we have $f(n)=x$ for all $n$.

Comment: I want to ask you, when you said $G$ consists of a singleton and $H$ is a two elements set.  For the case of $H$, the number of elements in $H$ is determined after Vlad constructed the coequalizer for the poset in that other post.  Also, the question there started with two pairs of pair of elements, so in the end, it weedles down to one pair of elements?  For the way the equivalence relation is defined for that poset question in the other post, the parity between pairs of pair elements can be both of the same parity or of different parity?  Also for the case of $G$, it is a singleton...

Comment: ...after the colimit for it is constructed right?  I seems to still have a lot of issues understanding these two questions.  If it is okay, can I trouble about [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629814/question-needed-for-clarification-of-notation-in-definition-and-specific-term-in)  I posted earlier.  There is something I am not clear about.  I mean after I sort out these two questions.  Thanks

Comment: @Seth Why are you worrying about pairs of pairs of elements? And ‘parity’ of pairs of pairs? It doesn’t seem relevant. I think you’re looking for more depth where there isn’t any depth at all. The point  is just to observe that $G\not\cong H$. That is all there is to it. A two element set cannot be isomorphic to a one element set. Precisely why $G$ is a singleton and $H$ is not, is addressed in Vlad’s answer. The conceptual reasons and your post here are addressed in mine. It’s hard to respond to your comment because the question is very murky (you are not sure what you are asking?).

Comment: By “not sure what you are asking”, here are examples. The colimit for G is not constructed, rather, G is the underlying set of the colimit of the diagram of posets $E\rightrightarrows\Bbb N$. $H$ is computed in the category of sets not posets, the distinction is important.

Comment: $H$ has two elements because there are exactly two things we need to represent, the even numbers and the odd numbers. $G$ has one element because when you also take ordering into account, you would find $\text{odd}\le\text{even}\le\text{odd}$ therefore $\text{odd}=\text{even}$.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. I have been feeling under the weather.  There is one last bit of a finer point i want to ask you.   Because the exercise asks about the colimit for a poset from the other exercise.  From Vlad's answer's construction for the coequalizer for that particular poset which you stated is different from how coequalizer for sets is constructed. ($G$ being a singleton and $H$ is a two elements set) Then is the colimits between sets and posets are different because their coequalizers are different, because coequalizers are also considered as colimits.

Comment: @Seth Well, I guess that the fact that the coequalisers aren’t the same shows the colimits in general aren’t the same. I wouldn’t call that ‘the reason’ but, whatever. Note that the coproducts in the category of posets ‘are the same’ in the sense that the underlying sets are the same as they would have been in the category of sets.

Comment: I keep forgetting to ask you about something from this post.  sorry i know is like two and a month ago I chat with you about this.  can I ask what the notation $\{(d,i;d',i')\mid \exists e:i\rightarrow i' \text{with } D_e(d)=d' \}$ mean?  specifically the meaning behind: $(d,i;d',i')$.  thanks

Comment: @Seth That *looks* like the construction of an equivalence relation from which one is creating a colimit for some diagram $D$…. but without context I can’t say! I’d guess $(d,i;d’,i’)$ is meant to refer to an ordered pair of ordered pairs: $((d,i),(d’,i’))$

Comment: oh ok ok. I thought there should be a comma instead of a semicolon there. by the way, I posted two new questions, one having to do with a counterexample about coequalizer and the other about small category. I will update the other coequalizer question tomorrow, since there are other questions about pull back and pushout I need to type up to post here tomorrow. Also, are you in North America east coast or in Europe. I see that you go to bed and are up at different time than me.

Comment: @Seth You can always check profiles: I am in London, I don’t mind saying. It is important you understand Vlad’s example. I would like to visit Canada one day

Comment: I understand Vlad's example.  I think for how he constructed his example for Set, once you know one element in the set of the integers, you know the rest by figuring out its equivalence relations.  Oh yeah.  I was a subject to her late Majesty the Queen Elizabeth II.  I would love to visit London someday.  :)